# Criteria API with ODER BY CASE expression throws SQLException: ORA-12704 "character set mismatch"

Tags: oracle, hibernate, case, sql-order-by, criteria-api

I am using criteria API to create my query. Because of special sorting algorithm I use an "order by case" expression. My Unit-Tests using in memory H2 DB and are working. In the development stage we are using Oracle DB and there I get an "SQLException: ORA-12704" when executing the query.

Assume my root entity 'Foo' has a Set of 'Bar's. Bar has an attribute 'myOrderByColumn'

```
public class Bar {
    ...

    @NotBlank
    @javax.validation.constraints.Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "MYORDERBYCOL")
    private java.lang.String myOrderByColumn;

    ...
}
```

Here is the code which produces the exception. It creates the Order object later used in CriteriaQuery.orderBy(..)

```
   private Order buildOrderBy(final CriteriaBuilder cb,
         final Root<Foo> rootEntity, 
         final List<String> somehowSpecialOrderedList) {
            
      final Expression<String> orderByColumn =
            rootEntity.join(Foo_.bars, JoinType.LEFT).get(Bars.myOrderByColumn);

      CriteriaBuilder.SimpleCase<String, Integer> caseRoot = cb.selectCase(orderByColumn);

      IntStream.range(0, somehowSpecialOrderedList.size())
            .forEach(i -> caseRoot.when(somehowSpecialOrderedList.get(i), i));

      final Expression<Integer> selectCase = caseRoot.otherwise(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

      return cb.asc(selectCase);
   }
```

I took a look into the Oracle DB. The type of the column 'myOrderByColumn' ist NVARCHAR2(255).

I guess the problem here ist that the "when" part in the SQL query must match with the type of the 'MYORDERBYCOL' database column, which is NVARCHAR2. In Java I use Strings. Probably Hibernate is not casting this correctly!?

I can produce the database ORA-12704 error by

```
SELECT FOO.id
FROM FOO
LEFT OUTER JOIN BAR ON FOO.id = BAR.fk_id
ORDER BY
   CASE FOO.myorderbycol
      WHEN '20' THEN 1
      ELSE           2
   END ASC;
```

This SQL works

```
SELECT FOO.id
FROM FOO
LEFT OUTER JOIN BAR ON FOO.id = BAR.fk_id
ORDER BY
   CASE FOO.myorderbycol
      WHEN cast('20' as NVARCHAR2(255)) 
      THEN 1ELSE           2
   END ASC;
```

How do I have to **adjust my oder by case expression with criteria API** so that the query is working **with any database?** (must later work with at least H2, Oracle, MS SQL, PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an Oracle issue to me. Which version are you using? You can try a different approach which might work.

```
  CriteriaBuilder.SearchedCase<Integer> caseRoot = cb.selectCase();

  IntStream.range(0, somehowSpecialOrderedList.size())
        .forEach(i -> caseRoot.when(cb.equal(orderByColumn, somehowSpecialOrderedList.get(i)), i));

  final Expression<Integer> selectCase = caseRoot.otherwise(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped solving the problem!!!
FYI: Our Oracle DB version ist 19.12 Enterprise Edition